# Angular app in Azure displays raw js text

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, azure-web-app-service

I've got an angular app that runs fine locally. I can run http-server and access the page. Now I am trying to move it to run in Azure. When I access the *sitename*.azurewebsites.net URL all I see is the actual text of my app.js file. Its not rendering as if it were on a nodejs server.

Here is the local directory structure. From the command line I cd to the app folder (app.js is in app\scripts folder) and use http-server to start it up. I see the angular app rendered as expected.

[image: local run]

In Azure, I have web.config files that points to app/scripts/app.js file. When I access the *sitename*.azurewebsites.net URL, instead of the angular app running, I just get the app.js file served up to me as text. Like so:

[image: azure raw]

Not sure what Azure setting is missing to let it know to run this as an Angular app. In the app Service I have an entry under Application Settings for Node:

```
WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION    6.9.1
```

Here is the directory structure in Azure:

[image]

Here is the web config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind
     IIS or IIS Express.  For more information, visit:

     https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config
-->

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx for more information on WebSocket support -->
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="app\scripts\app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="app\scripts\^app.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>

        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="app\scripts\app.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at online resources like https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wael-kdouh/2017/09/11/deploying-your-angular-application-to-azure-using-visual-studio-team-services-vsts/ ?

Comment: Yes - this was developed with assistance from folks at a Microsoft Technology Center. The CI/CD pipeline did not work as expected. It dumped a .zip file in the directory. Manually unzipped the file and now trying to make adjustments on my own to make it work.

Comment: My apologies - I spoke too soon. I saw CI/CD on that link and skipped over the essential - that it is serving up INDEX.HTML and not APP.JS. I made that change... and now I have the index.html file served up as a static html page. It still doesn't know that it is an Angular app. But thank you anyway - my day is ending but this at least gives me hope that if I look at it with a fresh set of eyes tomorrow I might find more that I've missed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well there were a few issues here but what I discovered :

1. the contents of the dist folder are all that was needed - I don't even have the web.config file anymore
2. the dist did not generate all files. The /scripts/vendor*.js file that was generated was empty. I fixed that by following suggestions here: [Grunt build not populate scripts.js with bower_components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186313/grunt-build-not-populate-scripts-js-with-bower-components)
3. Updated the App Service-> Application Settings->Virtual applications and directories to point to site\wwwroot\dist - this probably isn't needed, I copied the dist folder instead of just it's contents. If I put the contents at the wwwroot level I probably would need this change.